# Extracting the anchor from a URL in ruby

Tags: ruby, url, anchor

I looked through the [documentation of the URI class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) in ruby but couldn't find a way to extract the anchor (HTML) from the instance. For example, in

```
http://example.com/index.php?q=something#anchor
```

I would like to get the `anchor` text. Trivial solution is to manipulate the text with regular expressions but if there is some method for it, then it's much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module provides a [`fragment`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#fragment) attribute. e.g:

```
>> uri = URI("http://example.com/index.php?q=something#anchor")
>> uri.fragment
=> "anchor"
```